# Use a type generated from reflection as a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, parameters, fluent-nhibernate

I am getting the type to set from a string via

```
var resultingType = Type.GetType(stringOfType);
```

and this works giving the correct type.

Then I am using fluent-Nhibernate database mapping to try to pull the class (a table in a database) so

```
repo.GetQueryable<resultingType>.Where(e => e.id =1)
```

I'm not sure if the caliburn.micro is important but it WILL NOT let me call on resultingType. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what database in Caliburn.Micro? Since Caliburn.Micro is a MVVM framework not a database.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. But as long as I'm connecting to the database does that matter?

Comment: Just realized! Yes I mixed up Nhibernate and Caliburn.micro. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use reflection for it, for example:

```
var method = repo.GetType().GetProperty("GetQueryable").GetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(resultingType);
```

Then you can use `CreateDelegate` or `Invoke` - it depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really familiar with how to use delegates. Since I just want to return a list from the repo corresponding to a table in the database, do I just want a delegate and not invoke an instance (is that what invoke does?)? How would I create and use a delegate to get the list?